# Why are minor differences appear magnified when synced to the same parameters in Lightroom?

Tags: post-processing, night, lightroom-4

In a night photography setup, I took many shots in order to do a time lapse. When post-processing, I adjusted the first photo to my taste and then synchronized all of them. As for result, each photo looks very different from others having a different tint/color cast or whatever you would call it. I synced all parameters.

It looks like I magnified small variations between the shots by post-processing them, but how could they be so different since the setting are the same and shot taking one after the other?

D90, tokina 11-16mm

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE. Could you add to your question what parameters you have synchronised? If you synchronise the white balance [this answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/30897/9161) might be relevant.

Comment: Also how long were you shooting for and at what time?

Comment: Can you post some samples?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a fixed white point?  Were you using manual exposure control with a fixed ISO?  Are you sure that all of the rendering had finished after the sync?  If the images were truly shot the same way with the same settings, then a sync shouldn't be showing significant differences between images, so something must have changed between them or something is wrong with the way you are trying to sync in Lightroom.

If you can post some of the images so that we can see what you are seeing, it might help to make the answer more specific.  Right now you haven't given much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the white balance to either one of the presets or "custom" - if you use "as-shot", every single photo will keep their white balance "as-shot" - although that can be different between the photos.
If you have adjusted quite a few parameters in the first photo, those adjustments might enhance the previously subtle difference in white balance.