# How to consistently apply "global" color balance to multiple microscope images?

Tags: post-processing, microscopy

I have microscope images of similar samples, taken at different times with slightly different lighting conditions.

Is there a way to apply a "global color balance" to all the images, if for example I know what the (R,G,B) color of the background is?

Comment: Using any particular post-processing software?  Most that I know of will allow you to adjust say the white balance of one image, then apply that adjustment to a group of other photos.

Comment: If you can define "background" sufficiently well, ImageMagick might be the way to go  mainly because of the batch processing ability. It might take some effort upfront but will be definable and repeatable.

Comment: Just to clarify that you wish to affect a batch of similar macro/microscopic images taken under different lighting conditions in the same way. The short answer is yes irrespective of any subject or current colour coordinates. By the same token, it's also possible to bring  a variety of different known backgrounds to a specified background value.

Comment: @MikeW gimp, imagemagik, imagej or other free software.

Comment: @ChrisH can you post a link to a code example?

Comment: @Stan how do I *actually* do it?

Comment: It would depend heavily on your samples and background - [here](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/autowhite/index.php)'s a simple approach which effectively assumes a white background.  [Here](http://fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/whitebalance/index.php)'s another method (same author). I suggest you treat them as a learning tool rather than using them blindly.

Comment: Also related: [GIMP scripting to do *auto* white-balance](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/63704/26575)

Comment: @Sparkler - The specific instructions and procedure to follow is different for every software application. In two instances, they differ from one version to another. Whichever Image Processing software application you choose for your computer operating system, know that it was of major concern to include this basic capability in every program. In your case you wish to do the opposite of removing a colour cast (overall tint)